# Javascript Date inconsistency

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

On my node server, I receive time value from the client in epoch format (milliseconds since Jan 1 1970). I feed it into the `Date()` object and print it like so:

```
var d = new Date(epochTime);
var year = d.getFullYear();
var mo = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDay();

console.log("ISO:" + d.toISOString() + "  year:" + year + " mo:" + mo + " day:" + day);
```

Now, I get weird inconsistency from the date object. 
E.g. for the value of "1437386620207.58" - this is what above `console.log` prints:

```
ISO:2015-07-20T10:03:40.207Z  year:2015 mo:6 day:1
```

Huh? Why are those dates so different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems in your code:

- Months are zero-based in Javascript, i.e. `0` is January and `11` is December.
- [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns the day of the week. That should be [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) instead to return the day of the month.